# compare i and i+1 element oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, cursor

I have table

```
CREATE table table_x 
(
        id NUMBER,  -- ID
        NUMBER_history NUMBER, --  consecutive number
        start_date date,    -- start_date  of next id=end_date of previous
        end_date date   -- should be >=start_date 
);
 INSERT INTO table_x VALUES  (14 , 1, '13-NOV-92' ,'14-NOV-92' );
 INSERT INTO table_x VALUES  (15 , 2, '14-NOV-92' ,'16-NOV-92' );
 INSERT INTO table_x VALUES  (19 , 3, '16-NOV-92' ,'18-NOV-92' );
 INSERT INTO table_x VALUES  (11 , 4, '18-NOV-92' ,'14-NOV-93' );
 INSERT INTO table_x VALUES  (17 , 5, '15-NOV-93' ,'16-NOV-93' );
 INSERT INTO table_x VALUES  (151 , 6, '16-NOV-93' ,'17-NOV-93' );
 INSERT INTO table_x VALUES  (139 , 7, '17-NOV-93' ,'18-NOV-93' );
 INSERT INTO table_x VALUES  (121 , 8, '19-NOV-93' ,'20-DEC-93' );
 INSERT INTO table_x VALUES  (822 , 9, '20-DEC-93' ,'20-DEC-93' );
```

I want write query where I can find where start_date of next row > end_date of previous. they must be equal.

I try to do something like that using NUMBER_history as counter. C-way where I organize cycle by variable i and compare i and i+1 (NUMBER_history and NUMBER_history+1)

```
select * INTO row_tblx from table_x where NUMBER_history=NUMBER_history and end_date<(select start_date from table_x where NUMBER_history=NUMBER_history+1);
```

but I must organize loop by n_counter from 1 to last NUMBER_history value and fetch data into multiple row.
How can I do it?
I try

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
CURSOR cur IS
      SELECT * FROM table_x;
TYPE row_tblx_type
IS
TABLE OF cur%ROWTYPE;
row_tblx row_tblx_type;

  rowx  cur%ROWTYPE;
  nh_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
FOR NUMBER_history IN cur LOOP
select * INTO row_tblx from table_x where NUMBER_history=NUMBER_history and end_date<(select start_date from table_x where NUMBER_history=NUMBER_history+1);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (row_tblx(NUMBER_history).id);
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

How can I do it using for or another loop, multiple records or table of records , cursor, an table row as counter (NUMBER_history)?
How can I do it without cursor?

Comment: Usually I try to be understanding of poor English (not everyone is an English speaker). However, something like this cannot be excused by poor English: "find where start date ... > end date. **They must be equal**." Seriously, can you please check what you write before you post it? I stopped reading beyond that point. You are lucky others are more forgiving, but you may not be as lucky next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need PL/SQL or a loop for that:

```
select *
from (
   select id, number_history, start_date, end_date, 
          lead(start_date) over (order by number_history) as next_start
   from table_x
) t
where next_start > end_date;
```

Comment: Great! I feel that there is analytical function LEAD. This is best solution. But how can I do it with PL/SQL as if lead does not exist?

Comment: I would try to end my own solution cause some of its features could be useful.

Comment: @ifooi  Be precise with your question. Is this a conjured up problem, so that you want to learn PL/SQL? Or are you looking for another solution that does not use LEAD/LAG?

Comment: I want learn because of my goals and I want to complete my solution. Bit I would do it first. read more about etc,

Answer (score 1):

For example, here's a solution that does not require PL/SQL or LEAD/LAG function

```
select a.*, b.*
from table_x a
join table_x b
  on a.number_history+1 = b.number_history
where b.start_date > a.end_date
```

Comment: Thanks. Great. Self joining by consecutive number,